# How to read OSGI configuration via plain Java class

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I need to get some OSGI configuration values via plain Java class which is not registered as service so I cannot use @Reference or @Inject annotation. I have used Bundle context to get the config  but it is working.

```
public void getArticleName() {
        final BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ArticleNameService.class).getBundleContext();
        try {
            String articleName = (String) bundleContext.getService((bundleContext.getServiceReferences(ArticleNameService.class.getName(), " article.name "))[0]);
                     LOG.info("articleName......"+ articleName);
        } catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Service class

```
@Service(ArticleNameService.class)
@Component(
        metatype = true)
@Properties({
        @Property(
                name = "article.name", unbounded = PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY, cardinality = Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                label = "article addrnameess"),
         })

public class ArticleNameServiceImpl implements ArticleNameService
{

    private static final String ARTICLE_NAME = "article.name";

    private String[] articleName;


    protected final void activate(final ComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        final Dictionary<String, Object> configurationProperties = componentContext.getProperties();

        if (configurationProperties != null)
        {
            articleName = PropertiesUtil.toStringArray(configurationProperties.get(ARTICLE_NAME));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final String[] getArticeName()
    {
        return articleName;
    }
```

is it correct way of doing? if not what is correct option to get it?

Comment: I do not understand what you try to achieve. Do you want to get a config from configuration admin or a service property from a service?

Comment: I want to get an cofig value in plain java

Answer (score 2):

You can get any configuration using ConfigurationAdmin. For your DS components the pid by default is the FQName of your component class.

```
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
    BundleContext context = bundle.getBundleContext();
    ServiceReference<ConfigurationAdmin> reference = context.getServiceReference(ConfigurationAdmin.class);
    ConfigurationAdmin configAdmin = context.getService(reference);
    Configuration conf = configAdmin.getConfiguration("yourpid");
    String articleName = (String)conf.getProperties().get("article.name");
    context.ungetService(reference);
```

Comment: Hi Christaian, Thanks for you response. I am seeing compile time error on line 3, The method getServiceReference(String) in the type BundleContext is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ConfigurationAdmin>). Actually I imported "org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;"

Comment: You might be using an older version of the OSGi APIs. In this case try with ConfigurationAdmin.class.getName()